# Needs a .sql File

Tags: sql, mysql

I am wondering what a .sql file looks like.  How do I create one from mysqldump?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mysqldump -u <user> -p <database> > out.sql
```

It should prompt for the password.

Comment: so it just looks like a text file with commands?  That's simple.  Thanks.

Comment: Close, but not exactly a plain text file.  See http://marksverbiage.blogspot.com/2007/12/mysql-dumps-are-not-text-files.html